# Nearby and Text Search Zero Results

Tags: python-3.x, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get via Python the plain text result from the gmaps / places API. There is a Google Python Libary but wanted to use the real API via a normel requests or urllib call.

```
import requests
import json
import urllib3

#tried:

sUrl1 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=kindergarten&location=50.73464,12.52528&radius=50000&fields=formatted_address,name&key=[myapikey]'

sUrl2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=kindergarten&location=50.73464'+  r',' + '12.52528&radius=50000&fields=formatted_address'+  r',' + 'name&key=[myapikey]'

sUrl3 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=kindergarten&location=50.73464'+  r',' + '12.52528&radius=50000&fields=formatted_address'+  r',' + 'name&key=[myapikey]&verify=false'

sUrl4 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=kindergarten&location=50.73464;12.52528&radius=50000&fields=formatted_address;name&key=[myapikey]'

print (requests.get(sUrl1).text)
print (requests.get(sUrl2).text)
print (requests.get(sUrl3).text)
print (requests.get(sUrl4).text)
```

Did the same for urllib3, and tried to give it as params but always get this:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

When i click on the links (print (sUrl1 or sUrl2 or sUrl3 or sUrl4) ) - I get a wonderful result.

In my API Key there is a "-" but if this is the problem?

Do i need some more headers?
What is the problem?

Can you help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you add headers it works!
Code for Textsearch - works fine - needed to add headers

```
headers =  {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive' ,
            'Host': 'maps.googleapis.com',
            'Referer': 'maps.googleapis.com',
            'TE': 'Trailers',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1' 
           }

urlparams = {
             u'query': u'xxx Berlin XXX',
             u'location': str(lat)+","+str(long),
             u'radius': u'10', 
             u'fields': u'place_id',
             u'key': u'[mySecretKey]'
            }

response = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json', params=urlparams,headers=headers)
myjson =  json.loads(response.text)
print (myjson)
place_id = myjson['results'][0]['place_id']
```